# Calling onStart() after onCreate() with some delay

Tags: android, database, mobile, realm, splash-screen

Can we add delay in calling `onStart()` method of splash activity from `onCreate()`?

I want to call `onStart()` after 5 seconds. So that I can give enough time to app to create the realm database file on first run of app. So that i can log the on start of Splash screen in realm database.

Or is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: `calling delay in calling onStart()` only if you freeze the UI thread, and you get an ANR and your app crashes :D but I don't understand your problem well enough to provide a real solution

Comment: define handler with delay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define handler like;

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do all thing after 5000ms
  }
 }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Please note that if you put the app in background and then bring it foreground then now you'll run all thing after 5000 ms twice